# Trend values of a 3d matrix having nan values

Tags: matlab, trend

I have a 3D matrix (*19*-by-*21*-by-*23*) of mean AOD values. My dataset consists of `NaN` values at many positions in the matrix. I wish to calculate the trend of each grid of the matrix, but I am somehow getting incorrect results and mostly `NaN` value as the trend. Help me in correcting the code. The code I wrote is below:

```
y=1:21;

% = mat2cell(y,1*ones(1,1),21);
% Mcell = mat2cell(aa,19,repmat(1,21,1));

kq= zeros(19,2);
X = mat2cell(winter,1*ones(19,1),21);
for i=1:19;
    for k=1:23;
        u(i,:,:)= winter(i,:,:);
        kq(i,:,:)= polyfit(u(i,:,:),y,1);
    end
end
```

Comment: I wish to create spatial plots using the trend values.

Comment: What do you want to do with the nans? Replace them? not use them?

Comment: I do not want to use the nans and hence get the trend at each grid of the matrix, as even a single nan at any position will give me the trend value of that particular grid as nan value.

Comment: Using the above code is giving me an error. Please correct me for the same.